# Using the NHibernate object model (not tsql) how can I find out if a column definition has identity set?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am using some code that analyses the nhibernate model generated, just before I use CreateSchema.  I can get the Table.Columns nicely, but I need to test if a specific column has/is an identity setting.  So far I found that by using the Column.Value I can get a SimpleValue object, which has some sql for int IDENTITY(1,1) set, but I would rather not test strings.  If possible I need to remove the Identity setting so it just becomes a normal int/whatever else, column.

Any ideas?

(Note that I cannot use TSQL to test this, this must be done in code through the NHibernate object model)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Little confused on what you're attempting to do. If you have the identity generator set on a class, it should be available as part of the class's NHibernate metadata.